# Bash: replace with alternating symbol

Tags: bash, markdown, string-substitution

I want to extract markdown from some sort of text (ulysses iii iCloud Text.txt file). The editor replaced all square brackets with the "OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" `0xEF 0xBF 0xBC (efbfbc)` and I want to undo this operation.

How can I substitute all odd occurrences with "[" and all others by "]".

EDIT:

As example I want to replace each occurrence of `x` to `[`or `]`:

`Some ￼xlinkx` -> `Some [link]`

Comment: What's the input and what output you expect its not clear.

Comment: Why would you not try to fix the source data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` for your purpose. With `sed -i` it will edit the file in place making the changes needed. To create a backup of the original in `file.bak` use `sed -i.bak`. The expression would require that you place the character you want to replace in the variable `char` (e.g. `char=x` in your example). Then the following would replace all occurrence of `x..stuff..x` with `[..stuff..]`:

```
sed -i "s/\(^.*\)\b$char\([^$char]*\)$char\b\(.*$\)/\1[\2]\3/g" filename
```

**Example:**

```
$ char=x; echo "Some xlinkx" | sed -e "s/\(^.*\)\b$char\([^$char]*\)$char\b\(.*$\)/\1[\2]\3/g"
Some [link]
```

The expression utilizes **word boundaries** `\b` to control the match at the beginning and end of the  experssion to insure first occurrence is replaced with `[` and the second with `]`.